# How does docker run on osx, does it use vagrant?

Tags: macos, docker

I use an older model MB Air and running vagrant is very resource intensive for me.

When using docker on OSX, does it just use vagrant behind the scenes to run my docker instance on ubuntu?

Comment: To add some personal experience to my answer below; I'm also working on an older Macbook Air (mid-2012) and found that Docker for Mac is quite unobtrusive, to the extent that I now have the Docker VM running continuously for weeks without having noticed any performance impact.

Comment: Which "*older model*" do you own?

Comment: @techraf  2010 MBP i7

Comment: First you wrote "MB Air", now you wrote "MBP i7" - can you decide?

Comment: @techraf I have both sorry!

Answer (score 6):

In contrast to the deprecated [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/) (which also runs on MacOS), recent versions of [Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/) **do not use VirtualBox**, but rather [HyperKit](https://github.com/docker/HyperKit/), a native MacOS hypervisor, which is built on [xhyve](https://github.com/mist64/xhyve). In comparison to VirtualBox, HyperKit claims to be more lightweight.

Also consider the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/) on the differences and interna of Docker Toolbox and Docker for Mac (emphasis mine):

> Docker for Mac is a Mac native application, that you install in `/Applications`. [...]
>
> Here are some key points to know about Docker for Mac before you get started:
>
> - **Docker for Mac does not use VirtualBox, but rather HyperKit, a lightweight macOS virtualization solution** built on top of Hypervisor.framework in macOS 10.10 Yosemite and higher. [...]
> - The Docker for Mac application does not use docker-machine to provision that VM; but rather creates and manages it directly.
> - At installation time, Docker for Mac provisions an HyperKit VM based on Alpine Linux, running Docker Engine. It exposes the docker API on a socket in /var/run/docker.sock. Since this is the default location where docker will look if no environment variables are set, you can start using docker and docker-compose without setting any environment variables.
>
> [...]
>
> With Docker for Mac, you get only one VM, and you don’t manage it. It is managed by the Docker for Mac application, which includes autoupdate to update the client and server versions of Docker.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't use Vagrant,  but it there is underlying VirtualBox machine similar to what Vagrant uses.   Things might be slightly better with Docker because the docker VM is very slimmed down version.  And you can pack multiple images into that VM in more efficient manner, because they will be using the same kernel and IO layers.

Also, note that with both Vagrant and Docker you can use AWS or similar cloud things to actually run your images.